# Writing from file to another file in Python from certain set of characters to another one

Tags: python, file, pattern-matching

I need to read whole .txt file until it finds characters '{{' (exactly 2 in a row), from now on it should save everything to another .txt file until it meets '}}'. The trick is those characters don't have to be in the beggining of the line, they can be anywhere. So example file might look like this:

```
    blablabla {{zzzzz
zzzzzz
zzzz
zzz
zz
}}blabla
```

and it should get all the 'z'. What would be the easiest way to do it in python 2? I found similar problems but nothing what would help my case exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a regular expression, and `re.findall()`:

```
with open('/tmp/in') as input_file:
    with open('/tmp/out', 'w') as output_file:
        input = input_file.read()
        output_file.write(''.join(re.findall(r'(?s)(?<={{).*?(?=}})', input)))
```

Breaking this down:

- The `with` lines open the relevant data files. You probably already have this.
- The `input_file.read()` creates a single string with the contents of the file.
- The call to `re.findall()` searches for:

  - `{{`, but excludes it from the result (`(?<={{)`).
  - The shortest (`(?s)`) possible match until `}}` (`.*?`)
  - `}}`, but excludes it from the result (`(?=}})`)
- The call to `''.join()` pastes all of the strings together.
- The call to `output_file.write()` stores the result into the output file.

Answer (score 0):

Or consider using something like the following:

```
import sys                                                                      


def save_lines(infile, outfile):                                                
    save = False                                                                
    for line in infile:                                                         
        if save:                                                                
            pos = line.find('}}')                                               
            if pos > -1:                                                        
                outfile.write(line[:pos] + '\n')                                
                save = False                                                    
            else:                                                               
                outfile.write(line)                                             
        else:                                                                   
            pos = line.find('{{')                                               
            if pos > -1:                                                        
                outfile.write('-----\n')                                        
                save = True                                                     
                outfile.write(line[pos + 2:])                                   
            else:                                                               
                pass                                                            


def test():                                                                     
    infile = open('tmp01.txt', 'r')                                             
    save_lines(infile, sys.stdout)                                              
    infile.close()                                                              


if __name__ == '__main__':                                                      
    test()
```

Answer (score 0):

Rob is right.  The above solution has problems.

And, the regular expression based solution given by Rob above
seems like a good one to me.

Here is a variation on that:

```
def save_lines(infile, outfile):
    bracket_pattern = re.compile(r'{{(.*?)}}', re.DOTALL)
    content = infile.read()
    for mo in bracket_pattern.finditer(content):
        outchars = mo.group(1)
        outfile.write('matched: "{}" at position {}\n'.format(
            outchars, mo.start()))
```

However, depending on your needs, you might also want to think about
the following: (1) A regular expression based approach provides very
little flexibility for syntax error checking.  (2) Regular
expressions do not support recursive grammars, that is, if the
syntax you need to parse (and we are talking about a parsing
problem) here contains or is expanded to contain nested syntactic
elements, a regular expression will not help.

Here is another solution based on an FSM (finite state machine).  It
might give a bit more flexibility for error reporting.  But, it is
much longer and much more complex.  That complexity has costs: (1)
development time (the regular expression solution above took me
10~15 minutes; this FSM solution took me several hours); and (2)
debugging (there's lots of logic, if-statements mostly) since there
are lots of ways it can go wrong.

Because it is based on an FSM, it also could not be extended
(without difficultly) to support a grammar that handles nested
(recursive) constructs.  For that you might want to look at a parser
generator.  See this for a list:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing

On the positive side, because the code below is based on an FSM,
you can draw a state transition diagram to clarify what action that
code is suppose to take in any given situation (for example, just
seen a left-curly-bracket, inside curly-brackets and just seen a
right-curly-bracket, etc).  On paper, I drew that diagram as a
digraph (circles for states, arrows between the circles for
transitions).  I don't think I can do the ascii-art for that, so
here is what a text representation of a state transition diagram
might look like:

```
start:
    [any] --> outside
outside:
    "{" --> seen_left
    [any] --> outside
seen_left:
    "{" --> inside
    [any] --> outside
inside:
    "}" --> seen_right
    [any] --> inside
[etc]
```

And, here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
Synopsis:
    Search for and write out text content occuring between '{{' and '}}'.
Usage:
    python capture.py <infilename>
Args:
    1. Input file name
Options:
    None
Example:
    python capture.py some_file.txt
"""

import sys


(
    ST_start,
    ST_seen_left_bracket,
    ST_inside_brackets,
    ST_seen_right_bracket,
    ST_outside_brackets,
    ST_end,
) = range(1, 7)

Left_bracket = '{'
Right_bracket = '}'


class ReaderWriter(object):
    def __init__(self, infile, outfile):
        self.infile = infile
        self.outfile = outfile
        self.line = ''
        self.pos = 0
        self.inchar = None
        self.prevchar = None
        self.char_count = 0

    def get_char(self):
        if self.pos >= len(self.line):
            self.line = self.infile.readline()
            if not self.line:
                return None
            self.pos = 0
        self.prevchar = self.inchar
        inchar = self.line[self.pos]
        self.inchar = inchar
        self.pos += 1
        self.char_count += 1
        return inchar

    def write(self, outchars):
        #self.outfile.write('found: "{}"\n'.format(outchar))
        self.outfile.write(outchars)

    def write_prev_char(self):
        #self.outfile.write('found: "{}"\n'.format(self.prevchar))
        self.outfile.write(self.prevchar)


def save_lines(infile, outfile):
    state = ST_start
    while True:
        if state == ST_start:
            reader_writer = ReaderWriter(infile, outfile)
            inchar = reader_writer.get_char()
            state = ST_outside_brackets
        elif state == ST_outside_brackets:
            if inchar == Left_bracket:
                inchar = reader_writer.get_char()
                state = ST_seen_left_bracket if inchar is not None else ST_end
            else:
                inchar = reader_writer.get_char()
                state = ST_outside_brackets if inchar is not None else ST_end
        elif state == ST_seen_left_bracket:
            if inchar == Left_bracket:
                reader_writer.write('found (pos {:d}): "'.format(
                    reader_writer.char_count))
                inchar = reader_writer.get_char()
                state = ST_inside_brackets if inchar is not None else ST_end
            else:
                inchar = reader_writer.get_char()
                state = ST_outside_brackets if inchar is not None else ST_end
        elif state == ST_inside_brackets:
            if inchar == Right_bracket:
                inchar = reader_writer.get_char()
                state = ST_seen_right_bracket if inchar is not None else ST_end
            else:
                reader_writer.write(inchar)
                inchar = reader_writer.get_char()
                state = ST_inside_brackets if inchar is not None else ST_end
        elif state == ST_seen_right_bracket:
            if inchar == Right_bracket:
                reader_writer.write('"\n')
                inchar = reader_writer.get_char()
                state = ST_outside_brackets if inchar is not None else ST_end
            else:
                reader_writer.write_prev_char()
                reader_writer.write(inchar)
                inchar = reader_writer.get_char()
                state = ST_inside_brackets if inchar is not None else ST_end
        elif state == ST_end:
            return
        else:
            pass


def main():
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    if len(args) != 1:
        sys.exit(__doc__)
    if args[0] == '-h' or args[0] == '--help':
        print __doc__
        sys.exit()
    infilename = args[0]
    infile = open(infilename, 'r')
    save_lines(infile, sys.stdout)
    infile.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #import ipdb
    #ipdb.set_trace()
    main()
```